# Extract salaries from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, list, findall

I'm trying to extract salaries from a list of strings. 
I'm using the regex findall() function but it's returning many empty strings as well as the salaries and this is causing me problems later in my code.

```
sal= '41 000€ à 63 000€ / an' #this is a sample string for which i have errors

regex = ' ?([0-9]* ?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)'#this is my regex

re.findall(regex,sal)[0]
#returns '41 000' as expected but:
re.findall(regex,sal)[1]
#returns: '' 
#Desired result : '63 000'

#the whole list of matches is like this:
['41 000',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '63 000',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '']
# I would prefer ['41 000','63 000']
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Your pattern can match an empty string, so actually you *asked* for it. What is the pattern you want to match? Numbers with a space as digit grouping symbol? Try `r'(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?!\d)'`

Comment: You could try this patttern `(\d+(?: \d{1,3})?)€` with findall to return only the salaries. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EUCGOw/1)

Comment: np.concatenate(re.findall(regex,sal)[0],re.findall(regex,sal)[1])

Comment: Do you want to extract only the numbers that are followed with `€`? Try `r'(?<!\d)(\d{1,3}(?:[ \xA0]\d{3})*)\s*€'` then, or `r'(?<!\d)(\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[ \xA0]\d{3})*)\s*€'`. See https://regex101.com/r/rwbpTx/1

Comment: thank you everyone!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will give you the capturing groups when you use them in your pattern and you are using a group where almost everything is optional giving you the empty strings in the result.

In your pattern you use `[0-9]*` which would match 0+ times a digit. If there is not limit to the leading digits, you might use `[0-9]+` instead to not make it optional.

You might use this pattern with a capturing group:

```
(?<!\S)([0-9]+(?: [0-9]{1,3})?)€(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBKDJw/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bu0IPM)

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace character
- `(` Capture group

  - `[0-9]+(?: [0-9]{1,3})?` match 1+ digits followed by an optional part that matches a space and 1-3 digits
- `)` Close capture group
- `€` Match literally
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace character

Your code might look like:

```
import re
sal= '41 000€ à 63 000€ / an' #this is a sample string for which i have errors
regex = '(?<!\S)([0-9]+(?: [0-9]{1,3})?)€(?!\S)'
print(re.findall(regex,sal))  # ['41 000', '63 000']
```